# How can I get eth0 interface

Tags: networking, matlab

I try to get MATLAB running in Kubutu but there seems to be a problem with the network interfaces. MATLAB support told me that there must be an interface called "eth0" but I have only an interface called enp3s0. I've read several articles about but none of them seems to work.

I already tried to manually add an interface eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces without any effect. I've also tried to add net.ifnames=0 in grub without any succes.

Comment: Issue solved. I also hat to add biosdevname=0 in grub

Comment: Please consider posting that as an answer - it may get lost as a comment

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved. I also had to add `biosdevname=0` in grub